# What is the name given to those 3 character constructs that represent another character or characters

Tags: c, terminal

Apologies for the vagueness; I barely know how to pose this question.

Can anyone tell me the name of that family of 3 character constructs that represent another character or characters?

I think they were used in the old VT100 terminal days.

I know C supports them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs). There are also two characters code called digraphs.

Answer (score 0):

They are called trigraph sequences. E.g. `??/` maps to `\`. You have to take care to remember this when building regular expression-type parsers for C code.

Comment: Note: trigraph translation occurs before the pre-processor translation phase.